# /usr/bin/env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory error is throwing in Windows

Tags: command-line

I am trying to deploy the hyperlegder sawtooth in my windows local machine from the below repository    'https://github.com/hyperledger/education'.

When I start the application using Docker, then I am getting an error for the  `tunachain-tp`   as below

```
tunachain-tp        | /usr/bin/env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory
```

I have tried to solve the problem in the below ways

1. Installed python and configured the path variable
2. Uninstalled python

But, unfortunately none of the solution is worked out for me.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: See https://xkcd.com/1987/ :)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not with Python but with your file encoding.

It is a Windows file (end of line `\r\n`) but the file should be Unix (end of line `\n`). To fix this on Windows, you can do this in Notepad++ -> end of line Unix. You can also use cygwin (or Linux inside the docker container actually) with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Which file you meant?

Answer (score 0):

The above is probably your problem.
Also verify Python version 3 is installed with....

`python3 --version`

On the command line.

Comment: `Python 3.7.1` is installed in my machine and added in the environment path variable