# Possible problem with encoding of Python Path in Hyperledger Sawtooth in Docker

Tags: python-3.x, hyperledger-sawtooth

I'm trying to run an example from Hyperledger Sawtooth , the code to the example is this one:

https://github.com/hyperledger/education-sawtooth-simple-supply

The read.me is pretty straightforward , just run :

```
docker-compose up
```

One of the pieces is the REST API for the client , which is written in python, I'm not able to start the REST API because I have the following error:

```
simple-supply-rest-api exited with code 127
simple-supply-tp exited with code 127
simple-supply-subscriber    | /usr/bin/env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory
simple-supply-subscriber exited with code 127
```

For me Dockerfiles and yaml are good.

I already discarded the following issues , and tried the work around suggested :

https://github.com/hyperledger/education-sawtooth-simple-supply/pull/30/files

https://github.com/hyperledger/education-sawtooth-simple-supply/pull/32

Found this topic in this site, but I think that's not the same problem I have:

[/usr/bin/env: 'python3\r': No such file or directory error is throwing in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005107/usr-bin-env-python3-r-no-such-file-or-directory-error-is-throwing-in-window/59793043#59793043)

Any ideas are welcome , thanks !

Comment: Can you add the actual code you're running into the question, not just a bunch of links?  This (and the extremely similar question you linked to) sound like you're replacing the code in images with things you've checked out on your host system with invalid line endings, and my blind guess is that you should delete the `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file that do this.

Comment: Actually the rest-api does not have volumes:.
I just want to see if any of the known issues are linked with this problem somehow. Since one is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this doing the following :

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

The issue is Git converted line endings to Windows format, and now you have extra carriage returns (^M).

An used Powershell ISE, and worked.